# Sum of Fibonacci series

Tags: c, fibonacci

I made this code that obtains the sum of terms of the series of fibnacci:

```
int main() {
  int previous, current = 0, next = 1,
      sum = current, threshold;
  printf("Enter the threshold: ") ;
  scanf("%d", &threshold) ;
  printf("Fibonacci series: %d", current) ;
  while (sum < threshold)
  {
    previous = current;
    current = next;
    next = previous + current;
    printf(" + %d", current) ;
    sum += current;

    if((log10(sum) + 1) >= 7)
      break;
  }
  printf(" = %d\n", sum);
  return 0;
}
```

And I need you to tell me from that end of the series the sum of all terms becomes greater than 7 digits. I have tried this and i do not know if it is convenient:

```
if((log10(sum) + 1) >= 7)
          break;
```

Because as I have understood **log10()** consumes a lot processor time and resources, ¿there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You're overly worried about performance. If a piece of code works, and doesn't have performance issues, then this kind of optimization is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest and most natural way is to test if `sum >= 1000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is O(n). You can improve your code by changing your algorithm.

You can cache this sums in a `cacheData` array.  ( `cacheData[i]` = sum of fibnacci series from 1 to i )

Calculate this array for all sum which are less than 10^7 .

Then use Binary search to find the first sum which is less than input threshold in O(LogN).

Comment: The code already does this. I think it's going to be hard to beat O(N).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan your code do a O(N) for each input. but you can do it once and do Log(N) for new inputs.